# Drupal - showing forums on the left side bar

Tags: drupal, sidebar

```
Using Drupal 6 : 
Theme is Garland 6.12

How do I add a link for my forums and show it on the left side bar?
I have tried the following(and it didn't work) :
1. Moved "Primary Links" block to "Left Sidebar"
2. Added "?q=forum/1" to "Pages:" in "Primary Links"

Neither do I see "Primary Links" on my home page,
nor do I see a link for forums.

How to do it?
```

Comment: Definitely not a programming question - this is Drupal administrative stuff, and should be handled at drupal.org.

Comment: Did that already. No response yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left sidebar works fine on garland.

Do you have forums enabled?
Is the menu item enabled?
Does the user you're testing on have access to forums?

Comment: Forums wasn't enabled. I had to enable it through Administer->Site Building->Menus->Navigation->Forums.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide more information on what theme you're using.

You should also try posting this on the drupal.org forum, as stackoverflow is a programming forum.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your link is incorrect.  You should just link to "forum".  Drupal will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your forum up and running, are you able to view it?  You could potentially create a block with just the link.  Then you would place that block in the left sidebar.  You could also try  to add the forum to your menu as it seems you have tried to do.  The link itself will depend upon what you are trying to show.  If you need help with the forum set up check this: http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-make-a-drupal-forum